# Is the .pkg installation order within an .mpkg deterministic?

Tags: installation, macos, packagemaker, mpkg

I've created an `.mpkg` package bundle for Mac OS X from a number of `.pkg` packages. In the post-flight script of one of the `.pkg` packages, I want to perform an action which depends on another one of the `.pkg` packages already being installed. Can I guarantee that the `.pkg` packages will be installed in the same order that I ordered them in PackageMaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my own further investigation, it would seem that:

- all pre-flight scripts are run, then all packages are extracted, then all post-flight scripts are run; and
- the order in which the individual scripts are run is not deterministic.